# IGListKit and resize UITextView

Tags: uitextview, iglistkit

I use IGListKit in my project. Everything was fine until the task of adding a UITextView to one of the cells arrived. When editing, the UITextView should increase in height depending on the number of rows. I know how to do this with a UITableView, but what about IGListKit. I read a lot of material and did not find anything else. Is this really a dead end? Sorry for my english .

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try so far? Which material did you read? May you also explain the context a bit?

Comment: Can you provide some example code in your current setup? Basically you need to self-resizable cell setup, have you looked into the `SelfSizingCellsViewController` in the IGListKit folder?